# When finding out the domain of differentiability of a function do you have to use $\lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

Usually I check first if it's continuous at the given point, then take the derivative (if it has several branches I take the derivative of each branch) and then put the value there and see if the limit on the left and the right of the point match. Is this correct? Or do I have to use this formula specifically? Isn't it equivalent?

Comment: How do you take the derivative of something you don't know to be differentiable?

Comment: No that's not the right approach. You need to evaluate derivatives either using its limit definition or using the rules for evaluating derivatives (the rules themselves being consequences of the limit definition). Your approach would fail if the function is being defined as $$f(x) =x^2\sin(1/x), x>0\\f(x)=-x^2\sin(1/x),x<0,f(0)=0$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why would it fail in that case?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In that case what I'd do is calculate the derivative of each branch and then plug 0 in either.

Comment: Try to plug $0$ and see what happens